# Inadvertently overriding delivery pipeline steps using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I created a Jenkinsfile and added a method to checkout a repo:

```
 def checkout(branch){
    sshagent (credentials: ['ssh-jenkins-default']) {
        withEnv(["PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'Maven 3.3'}/bin","connectionUrl=scm:git:${SCM_URL}", "MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.home=${WORKSPACE}"]) {
            sh "mvn -B scm:checkout -DconnectionUrl=${env.connectionUrl} -DcheckoutDirectory=target/checkout -DscmVersion=${branch} -DscmVersionType=branch"
        }
    }
}
```

I then created a stage which uses the "**checkout: General SCM**" pipeline step.

```
if (BRANCH_NAME ==~ /someregex}/){
    stage name: 'DEPLOY' , concurrency: 1
    node {
        ws("${WORKSPACE}"){
            checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '${BRANCH_NAME}']],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']],
                    submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'ssh-jenkins-default', url: '${SCM_URL}']]]
        deploy(BRANCH_NAME)
    }
}
```

The result in my console output was:

> mvn -B scm:checkout -DconnectionUrl=(obfuscated)
>   -DcheckoutDirectory=target/checkout -**DscmVersion=[poll:false, scm:[:GitSCM, branches:[[name:(obfuscated)]],
>   doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations:false,
>   extensions:[[:WipeWorkspace]], submoduleCfg:[],
>   userRemoteConfigs:[[credentialsId:(obfuscated), url:]]]]**
>   -DscmVersionType=branch

So it appears that the mappings for the pipeline step "checkout" were passed as parameters to my custom checkout method and assigned to the scmVersion property.  I don't understand why though? Is there a way to prevent the pipeline checkout step from calling my checkout method without renaming my checkout method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you accidentally hid the built-in `checkout` step with a method of the same name. Use a different method name, or use `steps.checkout` to disambiguate the built-in step.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent this behavior by modifying my checkout() method

OLD:

> checkout(branch)

NEW:

> checkout(String branch)

Comment: I answered my question but if anyone has any additional feedback please let me know.  I thought one of the advantages of Groovy was not having to define your parameter type.  I'm now worried what other methods in my other Jenkinsfile may inadvertently cross paths with pipeline steps.